# In what issue of X-Force did Toad slime Siryn?

Tags: marvel, comics, episode-identification, toads-spit, x-force

I was looking on Quora a few days ago and saw that apparently during the first few issues of *X-Force*, the writers decided to give Toad the ability to secrete slime from his hands and he used this on Siryn to try and prevent her from using her powers.

I tried looking up the encounter, but was unable to find it. Can anyone help find the encounter?

Comment: Technically not spit, but secretions are secretions and who's being picky?

Comment: Yeah, that tag is starting to be a little dated, since more things appear to be popping up where he uses slime without spitting, much like this instance with Siryn. Maybe toads-slime instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're describing [***X-Force Vol. 1 #7.***](https://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/X-Force_Vol_1_7)   (1992)

[image: Toad sliming Syrin]